# Rx2 blockingFirst() doesn't work

Tags: rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2, reactivex

I am introducing in the rx world and I want to understand why blocking does not work when I subscribe to newThread. For example:

This is working:

```
int i = Observable.fromArray(1,2,3,4).blockingFirst();
```

This is not working:

```
int i = Observable.just(1,2,3,4)
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
      .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).blockingFirst();
```

And if is posible to make the second case works.

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The operator `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` will queue all emitted items to be emitted in the main thread of the Android application. If you execute the above snippet in the main thread, the thread will *block* in the `blockingFirst` method, and will not have any chance to execute the queued instructions for the items - it's a deadlock.

In general, using `blocking` in Rx code is an anti-pattern; it's easier to just remain in reactive mode and do something like:

```
Observable
.just(1,2,3,4)
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.doOnNext(i -> {...})
.subscribe();
```

Comment: i also meet this problems ,when i used  
`.observeOn(Schedulers.io()) `
it's work.